# Isolation transformer = floating ac inverter

Tags: power-supply, transistors, inverter, troubleshooting, earth

Its said that, in AC power system at power station neutral and ground connected together because of this reason we get electrical shock, as neutral and standing ground are same.

Assume, if I power a inverter 24 volt DC to 120/ 230 volt AC, without earthing its output AC terminals, keep floating ouput terminals, do someone get electrical shock (line tester shows dangerous voltage) when touching one of the floating ouput terminals, as its not tied to buiding earth.

How this circuit is completed (electrical shock), in floating AC inverter system placed on insulator board?

Is this floating AC inverter equals to isolation transformer?

If from floating ac supply, we will get shock, how isolation transformer (1:1) protect, somebody touches on one terminal.

How this earthing done in isolated floating AC supply?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Floating supply is floating. So it may build up a large static charge with respect to earth. I say ***may***. Not ***will***. Whether it actually does depends on various factors and situation details. A galvanic path may keep these equilibrated. On the other hand, that then allows that some terminals of a secondary are now directly dangerous all the time. So one chooses one's poison. A known situation can be placed under management (GFCI, AFCI, etc.) An unknown situation is much more difficult to manage. But still there are good reasons to retain the isolation gained.

Answer (score 1):

I have run across two distinct and different types of 12 Vdc to 120 Vac inverters. By far the most common inverter uses a simple DC boost converter that generates about 160 Vdc. This is then fed to a full H-bridge output stage that generates 120 Vac. They call this a "Modified Sine Wave" inverter. In reality, it is a square-wave output with sufficient off-time that the 160 Vdc supply approximates 120 Vac.

This type of inverter will be destroyed if you ground one of the output terminals to either side of the incoming DC supply.

However, the recent 120 Vac inverters we are purchasing have a fully-isolated DC-DC converter.  Because the output of the DC-DC converter is floating, it is perfectly fine to short or connect one side of the AC output to either side of the incoming DC supply.

Note that I'm talking about Modified Sine Wave inverters in both of the above examples.

And, yes. You can safely use an AC inverter as an isolated AC supply ** SO LONG AS IT HAS AN ISOLATED DC-DC CONVERTER **